# Monitoring task progress from cronjob

Tags: php, laravel, cron, task, monitoring

I have many tasks from cronjob and I want to monitoring them like that:

[image]

I read Server Side Events, but it seems to work with long script, not exactly with my case. Because if I close the tab of browser I can't continue monitoring or watching the progress .

Thank you for your helping!!!